# golang - default expression of switch

Tags: go, switch-statement

refer:  https://go101.org/quizzes/switch-1.html

```
package main

import "fmt"

func ExampleSwitchGo101_1() {
    f := func() bool {
        return false
    }

    switch f() // "{" is on next line, go compiler will insert a ";" here,
        // and the default switch value is true,

    {
    case true:
        fmt.Println(1)
    case false:
        fmt.Println(0)
    }
    // Output:
    // 1
}
```

The output is `1` not `0`. Because the original article says the default expression of switch is bool value `true`.

**Questions:**

1. How many switch statements is here ? Since a ";" is appended by compiler after `switch f()`, I thought there are 2.
2. But
   2-1. if I write a `switch f()` without cases, it's syntax error.
   2-2. if I write a `{case ... }` without switch, it's also syntax error.
3. If there is only 1 `switch` here, can anyone explain the syntax?

Comment: You can find detailed instructions here [line-break-rules](https://go101.org/article/line-break-rules.html). The `switch f()` will be `switch f(); true {`.

Comment: @Trock I get it, the original value part is treated as `initialization part`, the value part become missing, and the value part take the default value `true`, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

This has been [reported](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/58558) [more than once before](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/33657). It's a quirky interaction between automatic semicolon insertion rules and switch expressions.

The spec about [semicolon insertion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Semicolons) says:

> When the input is broken into tokens, a semicolon is automatically inserted into the token stream immediately after a line's final token if that token is:
>
> - [...]
> - one of the operators and punctuation ++, --, ), ], or }

So a line ending with a function call such as `f()` qualifies for automatic semicolon insertion, and the line is rewritten as:

```
switch f();
{
```

Then this is a valid [switch with empty expression](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Expression_switches):

> The switch expression may be preceded by a simple statement, which executes before the expression is evaluated.

And

> A missing switch expression is equivalent to the boolean value `true`.

In formal grammar:

```
ExprSwitchStmt = "switch" [ SimpleStmt ";" ] [ Expression ] "{" { ExprCaseClause } "}" .

                                        ^ this is your auto-semicolon
```

So with automatic introduction of semicolons, your switch expression becomes:

```
switch /* simple statement */ f(); /* missing switch expr (true) */ {
// ...
}
```

This closely resembles `for` statements with e.g. an empty init, condition or post statement.

```
// valid
for i := 0; ;i++ {
}

// valid
for i := 0; i < 0; {

}
```

Or even

```
// valid
if i := 0; f() // automatically inserts semicolon
{
```

Though if you run `go fmt` on code like that, it should move the curly bracket on the previous line, so in the end it's unlikely to encounter this confusing code in properly formatted codebases.